# How can a translation preserve a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, rigid-transformation

I want to demonstrate that arc length, curvature and torsion of a parametrized curved are invariant under a rigid motion. However, when trying to do so for the arc length I get
$$\left\|\frac{d\alpha}{dt}\right\|=\left\|\frac{d(A\circ\rho \alpha)}{dt}\right\|=\left\|(A\circ\rho) \frac{d\alpha}{dt}\right\|
$$
Where $\alpha$ is the parametrized curve, A is a translation, defined as $A(\alpha)=\alpha+p$, with $p\in R^3$ and $\rho$ is an orthonormal transformation with positive determinant.
I get that $\rho$ preserves norm, but how can a translation also preserve it? Supposedly, the norm of the vector after the transformation is $$\|A(\alpha)\|=\sqrt{(\alpha+p)\cdot(\alpha+p)}\neq\|\alpha\|$$
What am I missing?

Comment: What is $\rho$ supposed to be?  Adding a constant doesn't change the derivative.  Furthermore does a translation change a vector's norm.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe sorry I forgot to specify, I have edited it but it's an orthonormal transformation with positive determinant.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} (A \circ \rho \alpha) = A \circ \rho (\frac{d}{dt} \alpha)$ is incorrect, rememeber that by the chain rule you're supposed to take the composition of the differentials of the maps $A(x)=x+p$, $\rho$. The differential of A is the identity and the differential of $\rho$ is $\rho$ itself (as is true for any linear map), so you're supposed to get $\frac{d}{dt} (A \circ \rho \alpha) = A_{*} \circ \rho_{*} (\frac{d}{dt} \alpha) = \rho_{*} (\frac{d}{dt} \alpha = \rho (\frac{d}{dt} \alpha$ where $f_{*} = Df$ is the differential

Comment: @TomAriel I see, thanks, but why is the differential of A the identity?

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Recall the differential $Df$ of $f\in C^{1}$ at $x$ is defined as the unique linear map which satisfies $f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + Df (\Delta x) + o(\Delta x)$. Since $f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) = x + \Delta x + p - (x+p) = \Delta x = Df(\Delta x) + o(\Delta x)$ we get $Df = Id$.

Comment: Thanks :) @TomAriel